# Parse string in nodejs to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

How can I convert **following string** into an array in nodejs?

```
"Content: [{id: 1, value: 1, number: 1},{id: 13, value: 1, number: 3},{id: 14, value: 1, number: 3},]"
```

I tried JSON.parse, but there was an error: **Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2**.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Remove `Content: ` first ? `string.replace("Content: ", "")`

Comment: It's not valid JSON, so JSON.parse isn't going to work.

Comment: @JeremyThille—that is insufficient to make it valid, the property names must be enclosed in double quotes too (assuming all the values are type number).

Comment: Agreed, both changes would need to be in place for JSON.parse to work. 

@VaadinDestroyer I assume you're unable to change the original format, and are still looking for a way to parse?

Comment: If so, first run the string.replace on "Content: ", then add the quotes using a method such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493506/how-can-i-add-double-quotes-to-look-like-json) (note this is Java, not JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given string is not JSON strigyfied, So try with following `replace` with having keys as strings.

```js
y =
  "Content: [{id: 1, value: 1, number: 1},{id: 13, value: 1, number: 3},{id: 14, value: 1, number: 3},]";

y = `{${y}}`;
y = y.replace("},]", "}]");
y = y.replace(/Content/g, '"Content"');
y = y.replace(/id/g, '"id"');
y = y.replace(/value/g, '"value"');
y = y.replace(/number/g, '"number"');


str = JSON.parse(y);

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove "Content:", and then you need to make the string json-compliant, like so.

```
const a = '[{"id": 1, "value": 1, "number": 1}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "Content: [{id: 1, value: 1, number: 1},{id: 13, value: 1, number: 3},{id: 14, value: 1, number: 3},]".substring(8);
```

This is resolve problem "**Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2.**".
And you dont need **JSON.parse** already.

Answer (score 0):

I know people does't like to use `eval()`, but for doing some kind of things is useful.

Check this:

```js
var string = "Content: [{id: 1, value: 1, number: 1},{id: 13, value: 1, number: 3},{id: 14, value: 1, number: 3},]";
var array = eval(string);

console.log(array);
```